# Is it possible to make the "Material Select Component" with pure HTML and CSS?

Tags: drop-down-menu, material-design, angular-material2

Is it possible to make the "Material Select Component" with pure HTML and CSS?

It should look this this example:

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material has no such functionality. Why don't you base it off [Material Design Components (MDC)](https://material.io/components/web)? They have demos for CSS-based selects, buttons, etc.!

You can also view the source code of the MDC demo website to learn more.